Extract fill color information from PPT Table
In a PowerPoint presentation, I have a table where one column is filled with different colors. Is it possible to automate to identify/extract the RGB values or color of the fill in each cell?
Tried pptx library and not able to extract fill color information.

PowerPoint tables have a .Cell "array". You can address each cell with .Cell(row,column). Each cell has a .Shape object with various properties you can query/change. To get the color of the cell in VBA (you'll have to Pythonize this): .Cell(1, 1).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB

Given the PowerPointExample.pptx has a table as first shape on first slide and some of the cells have solid fill color as RGB color, then the following should work to get the fill colors:
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_FILL
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_COLOR_TYPE

presentation = Presentation('./PowerPointExample.pptx')
slide = presentation.slides[0]
table = slide.shapes[0].table
for cell in table.iter_cells():
    fill_format = cell.fill
    if fill_format.type == MSO_FILL.SOLID:
        fore_color = fill_format.fore_color
        if fore_color.type == MSO_COLOR_TYPE.RGB:
            print('MSO_FILL.SOLID fore_color:' + str(fore_color.rgb))

Why fore_color and not back_color? Because cells have pattern fill and solid patterns show only fore color while back color is the color behind the pattern. This will only be visible for not solid pattern.
If MSO_COLOR_TYPE will be MSO_COLOR_TYPE.SCHEME, then only fore_color.theme_color can be got but not RGB.
And cells also could be colored by a table style. And getting that is not supported by python.pptx.



If MSO_COLOR_TYPE will be MSO_COLOR_TYPE.SCHEME ... Interesting. In VBA/COM automation, requesting the fore_color will give you the RGB values, even for shapes that are scheme/theme colored. Setting the fill to an RGB value will override the scheme/them and set it to the specific RGB color though.



@Steve Rindsberg: VBA/COM automation has access to full PowerPoint Application to get what it wants. But python-pptx not needs any PowerPoint Application. It only reads Office Open XML from the *.pptx file. To get RGB from fore_color.theme_color it would need access to the /ppt/theme/theme1.xml part. But up to now it has not.

I see.  Thanks for the additional information. Appreciated!
